# Problem of constructing binary sequence with least possible 1s under given constraint

Tags: graphs, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, set-cover

You are given a binary pattern p. Problem is to construct a binary sequence of length n such that by sliding p over our sequence there is always at least one position where two 1s align (one in the pattern and other in our sequence).

The goal is to minimize the number of ones in the sequence.

For example let p = 101,then our sequence might be 0011001100...

if we set p = 1011
then out sequence might be 000110001100011

For small patterns it's quite easy to prove that these are the optimal sequences, but I couldn't generalize anything for more complex patterns.

This looks like a known problem but I wasn't able to find anything about it.
I think it is a special version of a [set cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) problem which is NP hard (for patterns with only 2 ones it can even be turned into [edge cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_cover)) - interpret every placement of pattern as element of a set S and every position in our sequence as subset of S which only contains placements of p that contain that position. Then let U be the family of those subsets. Problem is to cover S using the least possible subsets from U. Although this might be over-generalization because in our problem every subset is of the same size.